# My if statement is not allowing a change to an non-indexed array value

Tags: php

In the script below I have an array. My array stores all the links, titles and descriptions from a web page. But I want to make sure that if there is no description, it will use the first 20 characters of a p tag using a function which works. Only problem is I have the jigsaw pieces and just can't seem to put them together, So I want my if statement to show that if the description is empty to use the function getWord instead of getMetas().

```
function getMetas($link) {
    $str1 = file_get_contents($link);    

    if (strlen($str1)>0) {
        preg_match_all( '/<meta.*?name=("|\')description("|\').*?content=("|\')(.*?)("|\')/i', $str1, $description);
        if (count($description) > 1) {
            return $description[4];   
        }

    }


}
```

then my function goes here but there is no need to see that as i know that works.

```
function getWord() {
    $html = file_get_contents($link);    
    preg_match('%(<p[^>]*>.*?</p>)%i', $html, $re);
    $res = get_custom_excerpt($re[1]);
}



$outputs = array();

foreach ($links as $thisLink) {
    $output[] = array("link" => $thisLink, "title" => Titles($thisLink), "description" => getMetas($thisLink));

    if ($output['description'] == null) {
        $output['description'] = $res;
    }

    $outputs[] = $output;
}
print_r($output);
```

Comment: Why are you not using `get_meta_tags()`?

Comment: `if ($output['description'] == null) {`
might very well work properly (if the string is empty, otherwise use `trim`) but `$res` is very likely to be always empty...